# Use updateOn: 'blur' in Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular

I would like to start the validation of the fields of my forms only when the user leave the field (`onblur`).

I'm trying in this way:

```js
    this.profileForm = this.fb.group({
                firstName: ['initial value',
                    [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i)],
                    [forbiddenNameValidatorAsync()],
                    { updateOn: 'blur' }
                ],
                lastName: ['b']
            });
```

But in this way it does not work.
The validations (sync and async) are performed during onChange.

I would also like to ask how you can verify the name by making checks on the `lastName`.

Example: I would like the name field to be disabled if it is the same as the last name (only name field, not entire form not both fields).

Comment: Can you put the html with the field, please ?

Comment: it's expected that the validator would be called at least twice

Comment: if it's more than that provide a stackBlitz

Comment: Oops this options won't work if you are working with `FormBuilder`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Set params as [AbstractControlOptions](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlOptions)

```js
    firstName: ['initial value',{
         validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i)],
         asyncValidators: [forbiddenNameValidatorAsync()],
         updateOn: 'blur'
    }],
```

Example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdna17?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Thank you, it works. Unfortunately the object is not types and the content assist didn't help me.

Comment: may i have a sample of your async validator... is it what we use for username and stuff?

Comment: what about update with delay... for example in my select i choose US country for 2 second

Comment: Hello, is there a solution tu update with blur AND submit ?