# How to user updateOn blur in FormBuilder

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation, angular-formbuilder

I have a custom async validator, and I want to set `updateOn: 'blur'` property using `FormBuilder`:

```
myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   email: ['', [Validators.required], [this.myAsyncValidator]]
   // ...
});
```

I tried this but it does not work:

```
email: ['', [Validators.required], [this.myAsyncValidator, {updateOn: 'blur'}]]
```

**Note**

I DO NOT want to create form control instances manually like the following:

```
myForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', {asyncValidators: [this.myAsyncValidator]}, updateOn: 'blur')
});
```

Comment: you need use in the way "options" {validators:...,asyncValidators:...,updateOn:'blur'}, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52167148/use-updateon-blur-in-angular-reactive-forms/52167538

Comment: I think @Eliseo has the right idea.
Check out the docs: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlOptions#abstractcontroloptions

Answer (score 18):

there are two ways to achieve that -

```
myForm = this.formBuilder.group({email: this.formBuilder.control('', {updateOn: 'blur', validators: [], asyncValidators: []})})
```

or,

```
myForm = this.formBuilder.group({email: ['', {updateOn: 'blur', validators:[], asyncValidators: []}]})
```

Comment: Welcome, Nawaz. Instead of just including code, could you _edit_ your answer to _also_ provide an explanation? Why do these work, whereas the OP's code doesn't? What's doing the work here? Is there a reason one of these syntaxes might be preferred over the other?

Comment: The second option doesn't seem to work anymore since Angular 14.

Answer (score 9):

I want to add more answer for this question.

Here is the code at the library:

[image]

So, from your question, look like you are trying to set `updateOn` for email `formControl` and you are setting 3 arguments. This is not correctly.

Change

```js
myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   email: ['', [Validators.required], [this.myAsyncValidator]]
   // ...
});
```

to

```js
myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   email: ['', {validators: Validators.required, asyncValidators: this.myAsyncValidator, updateOn: 'blur'}]
   // ...
});
```