# What kind of object should I pass to `FormBuilder.group()` in order to have fields correctly instantiated?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

While certainly this is a case of "bad method signature reading", this is not a duplicate of the suggested question, as what's been asked here is how to create a `FormGroup` object dinamically from scratch, not how to append controls to an already existing `FormGroup` object

---

I'm trying to create a component that dynamically renders a reactive form based on a custom input object, which defines the inputs to be rendered within the form;

I haven't got to the input part yet, currently I've defined a sample input object in the component's class itself:

```
interface FieldDefinition {
    id: string,
    label: string,
    type: string,
    validatorsList: any[]
}

fieldDefinitions: FieldDefinition[] = [
    { ... }
    {
        id: 'nome',
        label: 'Nome:',
        type: 'text',
        validatorsList: [
            CommonValidators.validatorsDef.fieldHasStdVarcharLength,
            CommonValidators.validatorsDef.fieldIsEmpty,
            CommonValidators.validatorsDef.nomeCognomeContainsInvalidCharacters
        ]
    },
    { ... }
}
```

`CommonValidators` is a class I've defined elswhere and that I imported into the component, which exposes some custom "validator objects", each containing a reference to the function to be invoked during validation (among other stuff), so, in order to access the reference to the validator function to be passed to `FormBuilder.group()`, one would do: `CommonValidators.validatorsDef.fieldHasStdVarcharLength.funcRef`.

Now for the life of me, I can't figure out how to instantiate an object that `FormBuilder.group()` would accept starting from this.

I figured the `FormBuilder.group()` method would accept a `Map` element as a parameter, so I've tried building a map iterating over `fieldDefinitions`:

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    let formGroupMap = new Map();

    this.fieldDefinitions.forEach(elem => {
        formGroupMap.set(
            elem.id,
            new FormControl(
                '',
                elem.validatorsList.map(elem => {
                    return elem.funcRef;
                })
            )
        );
    })

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group(formGroupMap)

    console.log(formGroupMap)
    console.log(this.form)
}
```

Of course this doesn't work, so I gather passing a map is not the way to go;

**What kind of object should I pass to `FormBuilder.group()` in order to have fields correctly instantiated?**

Of course I don't need the exact solution, but just the kind of object that I should actually pass, so I can instantiate it in my constructor.

Below is some console output, showing how the controls are not instantiated and how I structured the map:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addControl to FormGroup dynamically in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573797/addcontrol-to-formgroup-dynamically-in-angular)

Comment: @GaëlJ Thanks a lot, unfortunately not really, those answers explain how to add FormControls to an already instantiated FormGroup object, while what I need to do is to create one from scratch. It'd seem a bit silly to instantiate a FormGroup object with a dummy control only to remove it and add the others dinamically :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple object like this to create a form with formbuilder.group():

```
    const formObj = {};
    this.fieldDefinitions.map(x => {   
      formObj[x.id] = {value: '', validators: x.validatorsList} 
    })
        
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group(formObj);
```

The formbuilder.group() can use objects with validators or disabled property like this:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
   name: '',
   description: {value: null, disabled: false, validators: [Validators.required]}
   property: [null, [Validators.required]]
})
```

Comment: Indeed, I swear I checked the method signature multiple times and couldn't figure it out for some reason. Thanks a lot man

Comment: What is the type of the object that is passed in? e.g. for `description` above, what are the properties I can have in that object.

Comment: Answering my own question: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52167538/1361860. tl;dr, you can pass in a [`AbstractControlOptions`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlOptions) as the second value in the control's array.